# error in using "qsub" when allocating nodes

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, qsub

my script (13-4.sh) is :

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N sample
#PBS -l nodes=4:ppn=64
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -o $HOME/qpms9-2/out/14-4.out
#PBS -e $HOME/qpms9-2/error/14-4.out
#PBS -l walltime=100:00:00
mpirun $HOME/qpms9-2/run_mpi $HOME/qpms9-2/14-4 -l 14 -d 4
```

when i write this command : qsub 13-4.sh
The answer is as follows:
qsub: Job exceeds queue resource limits MSG=cannot satisfy queue max nodes requirement

my cluster has 10 nodes (64 core per node)

Comment: Nodes Configs:
Nodes : 10 nodes , Performance : 10 Tflops
CPUs: AMD 2.8Ghz and 64 core in each node
RAM: 128GB
Communication : Ethernet
Useable Software:
1- Dlpoly 2- espresso 3- games 4- gaussian
5- Gromacs 6- java 7- lammps 8- mathematica
9- Matlab 10- mpi test 11- namd 12- octave
13- siesta 14- OpenMp test 15- tophat-cufflinks

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with your scheduler. I don't know which one you have but you should search the relevant documentation and settings to see if there is a setting that is capping the maximum number of nodes per user. If you type

```
/sbin/service pbs status
```

you can find which scheduler you're using by checking which services are running. Popular schedulers are pbs_sched, maui, and moab.

I would also make sure that all 10 nodes are online. You might be able to test this using

```
pbsnodes
```

Depending on how your cluster is configured. Additionally you should check that the batch queue exists and there are no standing reservations.

Comment: As a bit of a side node the people at the super user cite might respond faster/better to these types of questions